# WP 7.5Beta2 (Mango) and WP 7.0 SDK together

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone, windows-phone-7

I have installed the WP 7.0 tools – the installation package comes with the Visual Studio Express and WP 7.0 SDK. Now I would like to install the WP 7.5 Beta2 SDK (Mango).

1. After installation - will I be able to select the target SDK for the application (like e.g. in the Android Eclipse) or not?
2. Will the new update replace the old SDK?
3. How I can specify the target OS version for the application?

In the release notes is mentioned that "*If you have Windows Phone Developer Tools 7.0 installed, you do not need to uninstall it before installing Windows Phone SDK 7.5 Beta 2.*" Does it means I will be able to select the target SDK for my application?

Comment: Hi ctacke - why you have changed the WP 7.1 to WP 7.5? I think the code-name MANGO is for version 7.1 not 7.5, check here: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=26648

Comment: More information about the confusion 7.1 vs. 7.5 can be found here:http://stackoverflow.com/tags/windows-phone-7.5/info, The SDK version is 7.1, while marketing name is 7.5...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With both installed, when creating a new project it asks you which version you want to target.
You can also change the version from the project properties for existing projects.

I have released a couple of 7.0 app updates built with the 7.5 tools, there are no problems I have encountered yet.